# On Flying Saucer PDF, why is whitespace being added after my bold text and how can I fix it?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, flying-saucer

I'm using Flying Saucer PDF to generate PDFs for email campaigns. We are experiencing an issue described below, where certain HTML elements end up rendering with an added space before puntuation.

First, here's my stylesheet to be used for conversion into the PDF:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    src: url('path/Montserrat-Regular-400.ttf');
    font-weight: 400;
    -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
    -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    src: url('path/Montserrat-Bold-700.ttf');
    font-weight: 700;
    -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
    -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}
* {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
strong, b {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

And the HTML to be converted:

```html
<p>Here is a test paragraph. First, we use <b>b tags to denote bold text</b>.<br/>Next, we use <strong>strong tags to denote bold text</strong>.<br/>Finally, we use a <span style='font-weight: 700'>span with an inline style to denote bold text</span>.<br/><br/>This also occurs around <a href='#'>anchor tags that include and href</a>.
```

Here is the resulting PDF output:

[image: HTML to PDF conversion result]

Note the spaces preceding the periods.

I've tried setting margins and padding to zero, and adding `display: inline-block`, all with no success. I've also tried tweaking the `white-space` property and that didn't work either. The issue goes away if I put the punctuation inside the tag but this is ultimately undesirable for my application. Here is what that looks like:

HTML:

```html
<p>Here is a test paragraph. First, we use <b>b tags to denote bold text.</b><br/>Next, we use <strong>strong tags to denote bold text.</strong><br/>Finally, we use a <span style='font-weight: 700'>span with an inline style to denote bold text.</span><br/><br/>This also occurs around <a href='#'>anchor tags that include and href.</a>
```

[image: Corrected result]

Maybe this is an issue with the font, or maybe on the Java-side? Any help is much appreciated.

*EDIT for clarity: My dev environment doesn't have the font available, hence the screenshots not actually having Montserrat applied. The issue as described exists in production with the font correctly applied.*

Comment: I have just pasted the plain html into a text editor and loaded it in my browser, no weird spaces before the periods.  I then added the stylesheet details, still no weird spaces.  It seems the problem is therefore not in the parts you have shown us thus far.  Suggestion: run the plain html and then styled html in your own browser to satisfy yourself that the issue is not here, then raise a new query focusing on how the conversion to PDF is done.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the picture you sent, the Montserrat font is not applied. There is definitely an issue with the `@font-face` css definition, and you should check the font files.

Except from that, I was not able to replicate the issue, using flying-saucer 9.1.13 and the font downloaded from https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat.

Here is the html I used:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Montserrat';
            src: url('font/Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf');
            font-weight: 400;
            -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
            -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Montserrat';
            src: url('font/Montserrat//Montserrat-Bold.ttf');
            font-weight: 700;
            -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
            -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
        }
        * {
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
        strong, b {
            font-weight: 700;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Here is a test paragraph. First, we use <b>b tags to denote bold text</b>.<br/>Next, we use <strong>strong tags to denote bold text</strong>.<br/>Finally, we use a <span style='font-weight: 700'>span with an inline style to denote bold text</span>.<br/><br/>This also occurs around <a href='#'>anchor tags that include and href</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is correct:
[image: Screenshot of the PDF showing correct spacing]

Comment: I should have noted the font isn't available in my dev environment, only in production. (The issue exists in prod when the font is correctly applied.) I'll check on the flying-saucer version with backend dev. Thanks for your analysis!